# Use custom maven plugin to provide compile dependencies for project

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Is it possible to write a custom maven plugin that defines dependencies that are available in the compile scope of the project using that plugin?

Example:

Using kotlin, I have to define some dependencies in the pom and a build-compiler-plugin that also defines plugin.dependencies.

What I would like to do is write a custom plugin, that uses the kotlin compile but also (somehow) exposes the kotlin-lib dependencies to the compile-scope, so all you have to do is to include one build-plugin and you get the IDE-dependencies + the compile behavior.

It would be similar imho to the build-helpers option to add additional resources to the build, but with additional dependencies.

Comment: Have you taken a look at maven-dependency-plugin?

Comment: I am aware of the plugin ... but not sure how to use it the way I need it to. Can the plugin add dependencies as if they where defined in the dependencies section?

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you're trying to do. Where would you like to get your dependencies from, if not from the maven descriptor?

Comment: First what kind of problem are you trying to solve? Can you explain that more in detail? Furthermore dependencies are by default compile dependencies (if no scope given).

Comment: I put my concrete example in the question.

Comment: You could create a parent pom that uses the plugins you need, and then just have any project pom inherit those.

Comment: yes, I know. But inheritance is limiting, for example what if I want kotlin+springboot? the plugin would allow me to use multiple features ...  I guess this is far fetched and my research was not succesful, but that's why I am asking here ... maybe there is a way.

Comment: What about using a `pom` type dependency?